# finger and who command usage

Tags: unix, solaris, finger

I know that the finger command used to display information about local and remote users.

`finger` --> display users log in on local machine, even if remotely.

`finger @hostname` --> display users log in on the remote machine.

`finger user@hostname` --> I don't know what is it used for?

and `who` command used to know info about the local machine users only, is it true?

I am using Solaris 10 8/11

Comment: Have you tried `man finger`?

Answer (score 1):

In general, in the *nix world, `man <cmd>` will give you the manual of the command in question. Anyway, to answer your question:

- `finger` : The finger displays information about the system users. This can include:

  ```
    the user's login name, real name, terminal
     name and write status (as a ``*'' after the terminal name
     if write permission is denied), idle time, login time,
     office location and office phone number.

     Login time is displayed as month, day, hours and minutes,
     unless more than six months ago, in which case the year is
     displayed rather than the hours and minutes.

     Unknown devices as well as nonexistent idle and login
     times are displayed as single asterisks.
  ```
- `finger @hostname` : print the list of users connected to the remote host `hostname` ([source](https://pangea.stanford.edu/computing/unix/netcommands/finger.php))
- `finger user@hostname` : get the details of the user `user` on the remote system `hostname`.

Comment: I know what you said from `man`, but I know it doesn't use to check the log in users???

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean.

Comment: I mean is it used to check for the log in users or for any user on the system

Comment: Ah, according to [this](https://pangea.stanford.edu/computing/unix/netcommands/finger.php) page, only the logged in users.